# How to sum resistors in parallel and series?

Tags: resistors, parallel, series

I know how to add resistors in parallel and resistors in series, but i don't understand how to differentiate between resistors in the format shown:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjLKQa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I haven't been able to figure it out on my own and my lecturer hasn't helped either so i hope someone here is able to. Thanks.

Comment: How to differentiate between resistors? That's easy - they have labels R1 through R5.

Comment: Have you learned Delta-Wye conversions?

Comment: Nope, no Delta-Wye conversions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It often helps to re-draw the circuit in a way that makes more sense to you - it may take several tries to see the "real" circuit arrangement.

When I re-draw your circuit, the first thing I do is arrange it so that electricity flows from left to right, as God intended.  :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEjYKh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here we can see that R5 is simply between Vin and Ground, so has no effect on the rest of the circuit.  R4 and R3 form a voltage divider, which feeds another voltage divider consisting of R2 and R1.  If you had some values for the resistors and for Vin, it would be simple to calculate Vout.